# How to properly test in Jest for Vue 2 component's child component using $ref from parent

Tags: vuejs2, ts-jest, vue-test-utils

I have two Vue components, a Parent and Child.

What I am trying to get test coverage for, is, in the parent component, there is a function:

```
public focusToggle() {
 if (this.$refs.toggle && this.$refs.toggle instanceof Vue) {
  const toggle = this.$refs.toggle as Vue;
  if (toggle.$refs.toggleInput instanceof HTMLInputElement) {
   toggle.$refs.toggleInput.focus()
  }
}
```

The function checks for the existence of the ref toggle (from the Child component) and whether or not this is a Vue component. Then, if that component contains a ref of toggleInput, and this is an input element, to call focus().

Parent component:

```
<template>
...
<Child ref="toggle" />
...
</template>
```

Child component:

```
<template>
...
<input ref="toggleInput" />
...
</template>
```

My question is specifically, for a unit test from the Parent component, how can I test the above function?

Here is the current set of tests for the function. The very first (and most important) test fails, while following 2 tests pass, even though if I add console.logs in the function prior to running the 1st test, they all print out during the test (inside and outside all the if statements)

```
describe('focusToggle', () => {
let toggleWrap: Wrapper<Vue>;
let inputMock: MockServiceExternal<{ focus: (...args: any[]) => any }>;
beforeEach(() => {
  wrap = shallowMount(Parent, {
    store,
    template,
    propsData: {
      prop1,
    },
  });
  const toggleInput = document.createElement('input');
  inputMock = mockService({ focus: toggleInput.focus });
  inputMock.focus.mockReturnValue(undefined);
  toggleWrap = shallowMount(Vue.extend({}), {
    template,
  });
  toggleWrap.setData({
    $refs: {
      toggleInput,
    },
  });
});
afterEach(() => {
  toggleWrap.destroy();
});
describe('when $refs.toggle is defined and a vue instance', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    wrap.setData({
      $refs: {
        toggle: toggleWrap.vm,
      },
    });
    wrap.vm.focusToggle();
  });
  it('should focus the toggle input', () => {
    expect(inputMock.focus).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
describe('when $refs.toggle is defined and not a vue instance', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    wrap.setData({
      $refs: {
        toggle: {},
      },
    });
    wrap.vm.focusToggle();
  });
  it('should not focus the toggle input', () => {
    expect(inputMock.focus).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
describe('when $refs.toggle is defined and a vue instance', () => {
  describe('and toggleInput is not an HTMLInputElement', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
      wrap.setData({
        $refs: {
          toggle: new Vue({}),
        },
      });
      wrap.vm.focusToggle();
    });
    it('should not focus the toggle input', () => {
      expect(inputMock.focus).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
  });
});
```

});

It might be worth mentioning that these tests all passed until I migrated from jest 24 to jest 25. I looked at the changelogs and was unable to figure out why this test suddenly began failing however